# In Excel, how do I change the target range for a Pricetable being queried by an INDEX/MATCH array formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

So in the image you see two price tables, in fact there will be many more than this. On another sheet there are cells marked "width" and "drop" and when values are entered in these fields, a 3rd field marked "Price" uses a very clever INDEX/MATCH array formula (provided by a user on this forum, Scott Craner on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1439052/excel-table-lookup-on-column-row-and-rounding-values-up)) to query the first table (range) and return a price.

My problem now that I have multiple price tables is how do i tell the array formula which one to query? A further column on the other sheet identifies which product it is (Pleated/Pinoleum or Duette) and another column indicates whether it is shaped or rectangular. So currently there are 6 price tables to possibly choose from (a shaped and rectangular version for each of the 3 products).

Some sort of IF statement seems logical but the formula is already very long and adding an IF statement with 6 or more possible options is going to get messy. I assume there is a simpler way? Thanks

[image: PriceTables]

Comment: The best method would be to use structured references(named tables) and use `INDIRECT` Then you would have a cell that refers to which table you want.

Comment: I'm sure you're right Scott, but could you expand on that? So I name each of the ranges on my PriceTable sheet with a unique name, yes? Then how does the INDIRECT bit work???? Sorry....not great on Excel and very rusty after years of non-use (hence why I'm still on Excel 2007!)

Comment: useful [reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474B3A3A-8A26-4F44-B491-92B6306FA261).. || on the "have multiple price tables " part.. so your total input is now 3 (width, drop, tableName), right?

Comment: Why not use multiple if.. eg. `=if(tableName="Name1", <IndxMtch4Name1>,if(tableName="Name2", <IndxMtch4Name2>,if(tableName="Name3", <IndxMtch4Name3>,"")))`